# SPSS LOOP with VECTOR(index) gives spss-error 4023

Tags: loops, vector, indexing, spss

I have the following LOOP syntax:

```
 VECTOR tb= tb1 TO tb16 / X(16).
 EXECUTE.
 loop #i = 1 to 5.
 if (tb(#i) > 0) X(#i) = tb(#i).
 end loop.
 exe.
```

And SPSS tells me:

```
 >Error # 4023 in column 5.  Text: tb 
 >An expression contains a string of characters followed by a left parenthesis, 
 >indicating that the string of characters is a function or vector name, but the 
 >characters do not match any existing function or vector.  Check the spelling. 
 >Execution of this command stops.
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `EXECUTE.` after vector definition. That deletes the `tb` vector from memory. `tb` is stored in memory until the first `EXECUTE.`